# One word for craving for something that happened in my past

Tags: word-request

What is the one word for what makes one person think of something happened in past ,with strong desire?

E.g.: Something pleasant happened in my past life and it always makes me think of it in the present in a way I want to do it again.

Comment: Interesting. The first two words that I thought of are 'reminiscence' or 'nostalgia'. But I  don't think those two perfectly fit due to the 'craving' part. (But might be useful, I think)

Comment: Yearning. But you want a word for the **object** of the yearning. Is that right?

Comment: The first thing came to my mind: *blast from the past*, but it's not a word.

Comment: Does the word exist in your language? If so, what does the dictionary suggest?

Answer (score 1):

The best word I can think of is **["nostalgia"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nostalgia)** which means: *a feeling of pleasure and also slight sadness when you think about things that happened in the past.*

You could also look at the word "longing".